# Content in Tabs not crawlable. PhP

Tags: seo, web-crawler, google-crawlers

I have created multible tabs on my webpage but only content in default tab is crawled by google crawler. The content in the other tabs is not crawled by the google crawler when I check it in the text only version of cached copy. Can anyone have a look at the code and guide me what should i do to make it crawlable?

webpage is: http://www.itdevicesonline.com/SDX1-25C-BULK.php

Answer (score 0):

Just make your website display all tabs if javascript is disabled. Test you site with a [text-only webbrowser like lynx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_%28web_browser%29) to get a better feeling what google sees:

```
   Follow @itdevicesonline
     * Home
     * |
     * About Us
     * |
     * View Cart
     * |
     * Contact Us
     * |
     * My Account
     * |
     * Login
   [IMG]
   Call Us Today866-585-5130
   _____________________ [ submit ]
   Your Basket:
   0 items(s)
   [IMG]
     * Cisco
          * Switches
          * Routers
          * Cisco Network Modules
          * Cisco Power Supplies and Fan
          * Phones
          * Cisco Air Products
          * Cisco Security Products
          * Cisco 4500 and 6500 Series
          * Cisco GBICs and SFPs
          * Smartnet
     * Data Media
          * 8mm Tapes
          * AIT Tapes
          * Cleaning Tapes
          * DDS Tapes
          * DLT Tapes
          * DTF Tapes
          * Enterprise Tapes
          * LTO Tapes
          * Magneto Optical Discs
          * SDLT Tapes
          * T10000 Tapes
          * Travan Tapes
          * VXA Tapes
          * RDX Cartridges
          * SLR MLR Tapes
          * QIC Tapes
     * Hp
          HP Networking
          * HP 5000 Series Switches
          * HP 2000 Series Switches
          * HP 3000 Series Switches
          * HP 4000 Switch Series
          * HP 6000 Switch Series
          HP Server Options
          * SATA Hard Drives
          * SCSI and SAS Hard Drives
          * HP Memory
          * HP Miscellaneous Items
          * Power Supplies
          * Smart Array Controllers
          * HP Tape Drives
          * Solid State Drive
          HP Server
          * BL460 and 465 Servers
          * DL100 and DL120 Servers
          * DL160 and 165 Servers
          * DL180 and 185 Servers
          * DL320 Servers
          * DL360 and 365 Servers
          * DL370 Servers
          * DL380 and 385 Servers
          * DL580 and 585 Servers
          * DL900 Servers
          * ML330 and 350 Servers
          * ML370 Servers
     * IBM
          * IBM Controllers
          * IBM Hard Drives
          * IBM Memory
          * IBM Tape Drives
   Current Promotion
   CISCO
     * Switches
     * Routers
     * Cisco Network Modules
     * Cisco Power Supplies and Fan
     * Phones
     * Cisco Air Products
     * Cisco Security Products
     * Cisco 4500 and 6500 Series
     * Cisco GBICs and SFPs
     * Smartnet
   HP Networking
     * HP 5000 Series Switches
     * HP 2000 Series Switches
     * HP 3000 Series Switches
     * HP 4000 Switch Series
     * HP 6000 Switch Series
   HP Server Options
     * SATA Hard Drives
     * SCSI and SAS Hard Drives
     * HP Memory
     * HP Miscellaneous Items
     * Power Supplies
     * Smart Array Controllers
     * HP Tape Drives
     * Solid State Drive
   HP Servers
     * BL460 and 465 Servers
     * DL100 and DL120 Servers
     * DL160 and 165 Servers
     * DL180 and 185 Servers
     * DL320 Servers
     * DL360 and 365 Servers
     * DL370 Servers
     * DL380 and 385 Servers
     * DL580 and 585 Servers
     * DL900 Servers
     * ML330 and 350 Servers
     * ML370 Servers
   IBM Server Options
     * IBM Controllers
     * IBM Hard Drives
     * IBM Memory
     * IBM Tape Drives
   Data Media
     * 8mm Tapes
     * AIT Tapes
     * Cleaning Tapes
     * DDS Tapes
     * DLT Tapes
     * DTF Tapes
     * Enterprise Tapes
     * LTO Tapes
     * Magneto Optical Discs
     * SDLT Tapes
     * T10000 Tapes
     * Travan Tapes
     * VXA Tapes
     * RDX Cartridges
     * SLR MLR Tapes
     * QIC Tapes
   DVD Media
     * Blu ray DVD
   FARGO
     * FARGO Printer Ribbons

           Sony AIT-1 25/65GB Tape Cartridge - New in Bulk Packaging

   SDX1-25C-BULK Sony AIT-1 25/65GB Tape Cartridge - New in Bulk Packaging
     * Manufacturer:Sony
     * Price $32.70
     * Part No:

SDX1-25C-BULK

     * Availability: In-Stock.
   ______ [ button ]
     * Features
     * Technical Detail
     * Related Products

   General             
   Type                Storage media - AIT                                    
   Media Included Qty  1                                                      
   Media               
   Native Capacity     25 GB                                                  
   Compressed Capacity 65 GB                                                  
   Tape Length         170 m                                                  
   Tape Width          8 mm                                                   
   Features            Advance Metal Evaporated (AME), Diamond Like Carbon    
                       (DLC) surface, MIC (Memory In Chip).                   
   Recording Standard  AIT-1                                                  

   IT Devices OnlineServices
   [IMG] [IMG]
   [IMG]
     * Home
     * |
     * My Account
     * |
     * View Cart
     * |
     * Contact Us
     * |
     * About Us
     * |
     * Return Policy
     * |
     * Site Map

   Copyright 2013 All Rights reserved by IT Devices Online
```